# Separar una columna en dos a partir del primer símbolo

Tags: r

Tendo un df que tiene una columna como la siguiente:

```
      COL1
     x2000_0_14  
     x3_15_29    
     x4_30_44    
     x5_45_64    
     x6_65_y_mas 
     x2001_0_14  
     x8_15_29    
     x9_30_44    
     x10_45_64   
     x11_65_y_mas
```

Quiero separar la columna en dos a partir del primer guion, pero que no tenga en cuenta el resto de "_"

```
separate(datos,COL1, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), sep = "solo el primer _")
```

Para que quede así

```
     x2000   0_14  
     x3      15_29    
     x4      30_44    
     x5      45_64    
     x6      65_y_mas 
     x2001   0_14  
     x8      15_29    
     x9      30_44    
     x10     45_64   
     x11     65_y_mas
```

Datos:

```
structure(list(COL1 = c("x2000_0_14", "x3_15_29", "x4_30_44", 
    "x5_45_64", "x6_65_y_mas", "x2001_0_14", "x8_15_29", "x9_30_44", 
    "x10_45_64", "x11_65_y_mas")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")) -> datos
```

Answer (score 3):

Una solución relativamente elegante usando `tidyr::extract`.

```
datos %>%
  extract(COL1, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), 
          regex = "(.+?)_(.+)", 
          remove = FALSE)
```

A diferencia de `separate`, que solo nos permite un regex que hace match con un caracter separador, `extract()` permite regex que regresa dos grupos.

> Traducción coloquial regex-español:

> En tu caso quieres un grupo con todos los caracteres que están detrás de `_`, pero que no siga buscando una vez que lo encontró.

> Eso lo hace `(.+?)_:`, el punto es "cualquier caracter", el `+` es que siga buscando y el `?` es sí, sigue buscando, pero no te pongas ambicioso. Al primero que encuentras te das por satisfecho. El segundo grupo es `(.+)` es cualquier caracter `.` y no te detengas `+`, hasta el final de la línea me traes todo lo que encuentres.

Es relativamente fácil cambiar el separador y llegado al caso indicar que corte con números u otra especificación.

Answer (score 2):

Existen múltiples opciones para crear las columnas. Un abordaje simple es usar [`gsub()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) para encontrar los caracteres que coincidan según cada columna que deseas crear e indexar dichos vectores como columnas dentro de la tabla.

```
#' Retira caracteres hasta el primer símbolo de barra inferior '_' y el '+_' remueve también dicho símbolo 

datos$col2 = gsub( "^([^_]+_)", "", datos$COL1)

#' Retira caracteres que tienen al inicio el símbolo "_"

datos$col3 = gsub( "\\_.*", "", datos$COL1)
```

```
> datos
           COL1     col2  col3
1    x2000_0_14     0_14 x2000
2      x3_15_29    15_29    x3
3      x4_30_44    30_44    x4
4      x5_45_64    45_64    x5
5   x6_65_y_mas 65_y_mas    x6
6    x2001_0_14     0_14 x2001
7      x8_15_29    15_29    x8
8      x9_30_44    30_44    x9
9     x10_45_64    45_64   x10
10 x11_65_y_mas 65_y_mas   x11
```